# How to set a fixed color gradient scale from 0 to 100 for a heatmap matrix visual in Power BI?

Tags: powerbi, dax

1. I created matrix heatmap in power bi. The heatmap shows percentage utilization values at each hour of the day within a given date range for a selected region.
2. My next objective:

   - I want to set a color gradient scale for my heatmap matrix, similar to the one present in real heatmaps.
   - The lowest value (0%) will be light grey. The highest value (100%) will be dark purple. The values between 0-100% will have the shade of grey to purple as per the color scale gradient.
3. What I did:

   - I clicked a cell. I went to Formatting Options -> Cell elements -> Background color -> fx.
   - I chose Format Style=Gradient and set the following -> Minimum - Lowest, color value=Grey, Maximum- Highest, color Value=Blue.
4. For a particular region the heatmap showed the colors correctly 0 as light grey, 100 as dark violet, and the other numeric figures between 0 and 100 had shades between light grey and dark purple.
5. Now comes the problem. I chose another region as input to view heatmap of that region. For the selected inputs, the heatmap had values between 0 to 7% for all hours. No 100% value was there.
6. So, this heatmap colored all the cells with 7% as dark purple ! But I had set 100% as dark purple. Since no 100 value was present and 7 was the highest value, so the cell with 7 turned dark purple! That is unexpected !!
7. 7 is falling between 0 and 100. It is close to 0, so it should have some shade between grey and purple as per the gradient. This is generally expected in a normal heatmap.
8. What I did next:

   - I clicked a cell. I went to Formatting Options -> Cell elements -> Background color -> fx.
   - I chose Format Style=Gradient and set the following -> Minimum- Custom=0 color value=Grey, Maximum- Custom=100 color value=Blue.
9. then all the cell values turned grey.
10. I have to set a color gradient scale from 0 to 100 just like what usually happens in any normal heatmap. All the values for all the regions are ranging from 0 to 100.
11. I have gone through tutorial videos but those are showing me the same thing which I have done already.

Answer (score 0):

It sounds like you need to remove this filter from your evaluation context...

> "Now comes the problem. I chose another region as input to view
> heatmap of that region. For the selected inputs, the heatmap had
> values between 0 to 7% for all hours. No 100% value was there."

The problem is that the selected region is filtering the data you're evaluating, so you could use
`CALCULATE([measure],REMOVEFILTERS(<slicer column source>))` and it should calculate correctly.